# Defining Query gives different results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote a defining query for an entity "**BranchTotal**" (Created using Entity Framework designer). this entity doe not exists in my database.

I have created 3 scalar properties called

```
BranchID(Int32), 
TotalReservations(Int32), 
TotalAmount(Decimal)
```

My defining query is

```
<EntitySet Name="BranchTotals" EntityType="CarRentalModelModel.Store.BranchTotal">
    <DefiningQuery>
        Select r.BranchID,
        count(r.reservationid) as TotalReservations,
        sum(p.AmountTotal) as TotalAmount
        from reservations r
        join payments p on r.reservationid = p.paymentid
        group by r.branchid
    </DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

I wrote an sample application where I am getting the result. When I did the same in my main application, I am getting an error called

> Provider does not support conversion from Decimal to System.Int32

Code :

```
CarRentalModelEntities context = new CarRentalModelEntities();

var bTotals = context.BranchTotals;
foreach (var bTotal in bTotals)
{
    --Some code here--
}
```

Please someone help me what mistake I did.

Comment: Just in case, it could probably be helpful if you wrote which DB you are using and the exact types of all the columns that you use in your SQL query.

Comment: I use Teradata Database and Teradata Provider